# entity framework update code first with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

class person: id, name, addresses(collection of address)
class address: id, city,

Code first will create:
table address has the forign key personId, pointing to who leaves at that address.

How do I update a person, knowing that there is this FK constraint.
if i mark Entry(person).state as modified, when trying to add it I get an error if the addresses collection was modified. But I need to also update the addresses ollection

Comment: Programming language?  Compiler?  Some code that you've already tried?

Comment: Can you paste the actual source code you're using to try and update your person class? Also probably include your person and address classes.